# Crontab problem with process that take too long

Tags: cron

I have a script that runs rsync to backup some files. After finishing rsync, the script send me a email with the result.

If rsync takes less than 30min-1 hour, the mail is sent without problem, but if rsync takes longer, the mail is never sent.

Rsync never takes more than 3-4 hours (in the worst case: a clean new backup). The script is programmed to be executed daily, at 2am. So it can not be a problem of overlapping processes.

Is like the script dies after certain time, when it takes too long for a command to finish, and don't continue executing commands.

Sorry if this is a duplicated question, but I haven't found about this in the web.

Thanks very much!

Edit: The system runs Linux Mint 20

Edit 2:
This problem also occurs in Ubuntu Server.
Script file is in sudoers, to allow execute it as sudo without password.

Edit 3: Script code:

```
#!/bin/bash

script_path="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
now=$(date +$1)
path="/media/backups/"$now
log_file="/media/backups/logs/"$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
log_folder=$script_path"/logs"

if [ ! -d $log_folder ]; then
    mkdir -p $log_folder
fi

{
    echo ""
    echo ""
    date +"%d %m %Y - %H %M %S"
    echo ""
    echo ""

    if [[ ! -d $path ]]; then
        sudo mkdir $path
    fi

    sudo rsync -avprh --delete /media/disk/ $path
    sudo rsync -avprh --delete /media/disk2 $path"/disk2/"

    sudo /usr/bin/touch $path

} > $log_file 2>&1

if grep -i -q "error" $log_file; then
/usr/bin/php /var/www/email.php "to@email.com" "Backup ERROR" "<pre>$(<$log_file)</pre>"
else
/usr/bin/php /var/www/email.php "to@email.com" "Backup OK" "<pre>$(<$log_file)</pre>"
fi
```

Comment: Add the relevant parts of the script to  the question. Without that, it will just be guessing.

Comment: You say you run this with `sudo`? Then why do you use `sudo` in the script?

Comment: For some reason, it didn't work without sudo in the commands, and I didn't research more :)